# Codeigniter 3 form: keep data after submit

Tags: php, codeigniter

I am making a customers CRUD application with Codeigniter 3. The "Add Customer" form *view* looks like this:

```
<div class="form-group <?php if(form_error('first_name')) echo 'has-error';?>">
    <?php echo form_input('first_name', '', [
        'type'  => 'text',
        'id'    => 'first_name', 
        'class' => 'form-control',
        'value' => '',
        'placeholder' => 'First name',
        ]); 
    ?>
    <?php echo form_error('first_name'); ?>                                     
</div>
```

The form also has validation on some of the text fields. I wish the data that is imputed, *if data is invalid*, would stay after submit. What shall I add to the code above?

Comment: Your form submission is not redirecting a user to a different page? Are you using ajax?

Comment: I want the data to stay _if data is invalid_ and, as a consequence, the form is not submitted.

Comment: `set_value()` [method](https://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/helpers/form_helper.html#set_value).

Comment: I have used set_value() in the context above and it does not work. It works like this `<input type="text" name="quantity" value="<?php echo set_value('quantity', '0'); ?>" size="50" />` but I need to keep the syntax in the issue description.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the **Codeigniter 3** official documentation, this is how the code should look in order for the input fields data to be kept if the form is not submitted:

```
<?php echo form_input('first_name', set_value('first_name'), [
   'type'  => 'text',
   'id'    => 'first_name', 
   'class' => 'form-control',
   'placeholder' => 'First name',
]);?>
```

Comment: what you asked ***Codeigniter 3 form: keep data after submit*** and your answer is different.

Comment: No, it is what I wanted and what I asked

Answer (score 0):

In your form_input function, Set **value** key as set_value() for text fields , set_select() for select , set_checkbox() for checkbox and set_radio() for radio button. This will repopulate your from after submitting the form even if the page is refreshed. See below example for your first name text field, where i put value as set_value('first_name'). this function set the posted value there after validation put the form back.

You can see more validation rules [here](https://codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/form_validation.html)

```
   <div class="form-group <?php if(form_error('first_name')) echo 'has-error';?>">
<input type="text" id="first_name" class="form-control" value="<?php echo set_value('first_name');?>" placeholder="First name" />

        <?php echo form_error('first_name'); ?>                                     
    </div>
```

And on your controller, you must set the first_name in validation rule like below

```
  $this->form_validation->set_rules('first_name', 'First name', 'required');
```

You must set this rules for each field even if it is not required or dont have any rules. You can also leave the rules parameter blank.

Comment: I gave added `'value' => set_value('first_name')` but it does not work

Comment: And on your controller, you must set the first_name in validation rule like above and also ou must set this rules for each field even if it is not required or don't have any rules.

Comment: I did all that, with validation included, but still the data does not persist.

Comment: Can you try html input form instead of php input generator like this :- 
<input type="text" id="first_name" class="form-control" value="<?php echo set_value('first_name');?>" placeholder="First name" /> and see what is happening now ?

One question to you ? to which page you sending the form action ?

Comment: `<?php echo form_open('home/save'); ?>`

Comment: You must set form validation rules on save controller in order to repopulate the fields again after submitting

Answer (score 0):

As I know you can do 2 things on here

1. Use AJAX
2. Use session

Using AJAX means you can check [filed validation](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_validation.asp) + [from validation](https://www.daniweb.com/programming/web-development/threads/473386/codeigniter-and-form-validation-ajax) and then SUBMIT the form. So your data remain till last.

Or

Save it to session when submitting and the after redirect load it back to respective fields.